# Out of order tuples in Flink without windowing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does Flink handle out-of-order tuples even in case one **does not use a windowing operator**?

For example:

```
withTimestampsAndWatermarks
        .keyBy(...)
        .map(...) // some stateful function
        .addSink(...);
```

Will `map` wait to process elements until receiving the correct watermark or will it process the elements without waiting?

The problem is that the partitioned state that `map` holds could be affected by the out-of-order processing of tuples.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. Map operator doesn't work with watermarks at all.
You will get elements in the same order as in the input stream.

For further reference check the implementation of `StreamMap` operator where you can see watermark elements are just forwarded to the output.

[Github source code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.1/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/StreamMap.java)

Comment: Is there a "long" answer? This can be generalized to all the functions that can be applied after a keyBy?

Comment: Could you describe more detailed what kind of stateful algorithm are you using that the order of incoming elements affects the outcome? If you want to wait for some out-of-order elements use `windowing` instead, where you can specify "how much" the element can be out-of-order (`allowedLateness`).

Comment: I was just wondering if out-of-order tuples were reordered only in the case you use a window. I think you perfectly answered my question. Thank you